# $.(ajax) wrapper for Jquery - passing parameters to delegates

Tags: jquery, ajax, parameter-passing

I use $.(ajax) function extensively in my app to call ASP.net web services. I would like to write a wrapper in order to centralize all the ajax calls. I found few simple solutions, but none address an issue of passing parameters to delegates, for example, if i have:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost/TemplateWebService/TemplateWebService/Service.asmx/GetFoobar",

        data: jsonText,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            var results = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;

            OnSuccess(results, someOtherParam1, someOtherParam2);


        },

        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            OnError();
        }
    });
```

The wrapper to this call would have to have the way to pass someOtherParam1, someOtherParam2 to the OnSuccess delegate...Aside from packing the variables into a generic array, I can't think of other solutions.

How did you guys address this issue?

Comment: the problem is the lack of transparency, I posted this to find out how other ppl deal with the similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  My way around it was to include the parameter in the data variable and then pull it out of this.data on success/error/complete.
this.data will look like foo=1&bar=2&baz=3 when it comes back so you will need to parse the parameters out.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'blah.html',
  data: {foo:1,someOtherParam1:2,someOtherParam2:3},
  success: function(data) {
    var params = this.data.split("&");
    OnSuccess(results, params[1].split("=")[1], params[2].split("=")[1]);
  }
});
```

Make sure you don't get this.data confused with the data variable that is returned with the success function...

Comment: what if you have several parameters? do you have something like this.data.param1, this.data.param2, etc...?

Comment: no.  this.data comes back looking like foo=1&bar=2&baz=3 so you have to parse the string and pull it out.