# Using eval() in Javascript to unpack the array

Tags: javascript, eval

I have an array that I need to unpack.

So, from something like

```
var params = new Array();
params.push("var1");
params.push("var2");
```

I need to have something like

"var1", "var2".

I tried using eval, but eval() gives me something like var1, var2...i don't want to insert quotes myself as the vars passed can be integers, or other types. I need to pass this to a function, so that's why i can't just traverse the array and shove it into a string.

What is the preferred solution here?

Comment: I doubt you can get JavaScript to add the " itself, unless maybe you use JSON.stringify(). " are just the string delimiters and do not belong to the string value.

Comment: that's the thing, is that i would like to pass the VALUES of the vars...they may not always be strings either. I am wondering if it's possible at all.

Comment: How do you want "other types" to be serialised?

Comment: When you say "pass the values"... where are you passing to?

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a general solution, so at the point of passing I won't know how many parameters the function will accept. Hence, I shove them into the array. Then, I need to unpack and pass them. So the variables shoved into the array may all be different types:strings, ints, other arrays. When unpacking, I want to be able to do something like: DoSomething(param1, param2, param3) where param1 .. param3 come from the array. 

I posted here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836037/ajax-wrapper-for-jquery-passing-parameters-to-delegates/2836180#2836180

got no real answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an array of values that you want to pass to a function filling the formal parameters then you can use the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Apply) method of the Function prototype.

```
var arr = [1, 2, "three"];

function myFunc(a, b, c) {
   // a = 1, b = 2, c = "three"
   ...
}

myFunc.apply(this, arr);
```

By the way, the `this` parameter in the last statement can be set to any object to set the value of `this` inside `myFunc`

Comment: thanks, I never knew of apply's existence. However, what's the purpose of this here? I am not quite clear regarding "this". Do I need it?

Comment: You need *something* there, if you are uncertain use `this` to keep the current context, or pass `null` to use the global context. As I said, the first parameter controls what `this` *inside* the function refers to.

Answer (score 0):

This generates the output you want

```
var params = new Array();
params.push("var1");
params.push("var2");

var s = "\"" + params.join("\",\"") + "\"";
```